LangChain: How can sources be included in the response of a RAG system?
I'm currently working with LangChain and OpenAI to create a RAG system. The system takes a vector store of embedded documents as input, with each document having "Source" (a URL) and "Title" as metadata. It also has memory of previous messages.
I want the system to provide answers that include the metadata within the text itself, something like: "Cats love humans [Title2: url2], but hate dogs [Title5: url5]." However, I'm currently stuck.
Here's my current Python code:
 def get_answer(question, chat_history):
    auxiliary_system_prompt = """Given a chat history and the latest user question \
    which might reference context in the chat history, formulate a standalone question \
    which can be understood without the chat history. Do NOT answer the question, \
    just reformulate it if needed and otherwise return it as is. \
    If the chat history is empty, just return the question as is."""

    auxiliary_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("system", auxiliary_system_prompt),
            MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
            ("human", "{input}"),
        ]
    )

    history_aware_retriever = create_history_aware_retriever(
        llm, retriever, auxiliary_prompt
    )

    main_system_prompt = """
    You're a helpful AI assistant, working for the Support Team of Domotz, a tech company.
    Use the following articles to answer the user question.
    Follow these rules:
    1. If you don't know the answer or you don't have enough sources, do not answer.
    2. Write with simple language, but use proper, technical words if needed.
    3. Write at least 10 sentences. Never write hyperlinks, write the URL.
    4. Remember, the context is a collection of articles. Each article has a source: article.metadata["source"]. For each sentence, you cite the article(s) source(s).
    
    Here are the articles:{context}
    """

    main_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("system", main_system_prompt),
            MessagesPlaceholder("chat_history"),
            ("human", "{input}"),
        ]
    )

    question_answer_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, main_prompt)
    rag_chain = create_retrieval_chain(
        history_aware_retriever, question_answer_chain
    )
    message = rag_chain.invoke({"input": question, "chat_history": chat_history})
    chat_history.extend([HumanMessage(content=question), HumanMessage(content=message["answer"])])

    return message, chat_history

The fourth rule should ideally force the system to return sources, but it doesn't work -- it just adds  (source: article.metadata["source"]), e.g., ""Cats love humans  (source: article.metadata["source"])., but hate dogs (source: article.metadata["source"]).."
